# If $\{x,y\}$ is an orthonormal set in an inner product space then the value of $\|x-y\|+\|x+y\|$ is $2\sqrt2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

> If $\{x,y\}$ is an orthonormal set in an inner product space then the value of $\|x-y\|+\|x+y\|$ is $2\sqrt2$.

Using $\langle x,y \rangle=0$ and $\langle x,x \rangle=\langle y,y \rangle=1$ and the definition of inner product I can expand this expression and get the answer but I was wondering if there's a faster method since I'm only given a few minutes for this MCQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** By Pytagoras Theorem in an inner product space
$$\|x \pm y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2=1+1=2$$

**P.S.** You can also figure the answer by "drawing a diagram" of two orthonormal vectors... But one needs to be carefull, this approach works here but may lead to the wrong answer in some situations, it is a heuristic and not formal approach.

Comment: Do you mean like the figure drawn [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-pythagorean-theorem-for-inner-product-spaces) for the $\mathbb R^2$ case?

Comment: @Rhaldryn Yes. The reason why this works here is actulally the following: Consider the subspace spanned by $\{x,y\}$ in your inner product space. This is a 2-dimensional subspace, and $x,y$ is an orthonormal basis in here. It follows that the function which sends $x \to (1,0), y \to (0,1)$ is an inner product preserving isomorphish (this needs a tiny bit work but can be shown) between this subspace and $\mathbb R^2$. Since the entire computation can be done in this subspace, it can be moved throughout this isomorphism to the picture in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your numerical calculation is essentially correct, and about as fast as possible.

I think you mean
$x = \langle 1, 0 \rangle$ and $y = \langle 0, 1\rangle$. Then each of $x \pm y$ is a vector of length $\sqrt{2}$.

For a one line more theoretical argument see the answer from @N.S.

Comment: $\{x,y\}$ is an arbitrary orthonormal set of vectors not necessarily $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Rhaldryn That's true. But it's a good way to proceed on a time sensitive exam. It is in fact generic, because  the pair $(x,y)$ is an orthonormal basis of the space they span and you can use that basis to define a coordinate system with which to compute the lengths.